# AttributeError: module 'datasets' has no attribute 'map'

Tags: python, huggingface-datasets

getting

```
AttributeError:Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-36788303b378> in <module>
----> 1 tokenized_datasets = datasets.map(
      2     prepare_train_features,
      3     batched=True,
      4     remove_columns=datasets["train"].column_names,
      5     num_proc=3,

AttributeError: module 'datasets' has no attribute 'map'
```

from

```
tokenized_datasets = datasets.map(
    prepare_train_features,
    batched=True,
    remove_columns=datasets["train"].column_names,
    num_proc=3,
)
```

i am trying this https://keras.io/examples/nlp/question_answering/
please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably it's a typo.

The library name is `datasets` but the variable name they used clashes. https://keras.io/examples/nlp/question_answering/

They use a `load_dataset` without importing the `datasets` module.

```
from datasets import load_dataset

datasets = load_dataset("squad")
```

I'll suggest avoiding `datasets` as a variable and refactor the variable name to:

```
squad_datasets = load_dataset("squad")

...

tokenized_datasets = squad_datasets.map(
    prepare_train_features,
    batched=True,
    remove_columns=datasets["train"].column_names,
    num_proc=3,
)
```